# Power BI DAX measure being filtered in unexpected ways based on use case

Tags: powerbi, dax

Power BI DAX measure is being filtered in variable ways depending on if I put it in a table or if I have it displayed in a callout card

I have a table full of sales invoices that all have a locationID that indicates the location the invoice line is related to.  I need to figure out the historic percentage of sales that are coming out of these location ids dynamically.  By dynamically, I simply mean I don't have to use an if statement, I can simply use a slicer to switch between the locations that I want the calculation based off of.

The goal:
I want the numerator of a division formula to be filtered to only sum the dollar values of invoice lines that correspond to the locationid that is selected in a slicer with locationids.  The denominator would sum every invoice line's dollar value.  There are other considerations I would like, but mainly I cannot even get this simple calculation to work reliably.

I want to then use this number to find out how much of the sales dollar value target for the year each Location should be responsible for.  ex: Location 1 is historically responsible for 35% of all invoiced dollars, so therefore I want to multiply the company-wide total sales goal by 35% when I select Location 1 in a slicer to show the dollar value of sales that employees in this region should total at the end of the year.

my measure:

```
percent sales by yard = 
VAR SelectedLocationID = SELECTEDVALUE(LocationIDList[LocationID])
VAR Numerator = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Sales invoice lines'[Line Amount]),
        'Sales invoice lines'[LocationID] = SelectedLocationID
    )
VAR Denominator = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Sales invoice lines'[Line Amount]),
        ALLSELECTED('Sales invoice lines')
    )
VAR Percent_By_Location_Selection = DIVIDE(Numerator, Denominator)
RETURN
    ABS(Percent_By_Location_Selection)
```

I have made this measure several different ways.  On some I have used the filter function in the filter section of the CALCULATE function.  Others I have not broken out the three sections as seen above; I just did a division statement.  They all return the same results.

Tables:
LocationIDList is a disconnected table that has a list of values that represent the name given to a particular company location.  The [LocationID] column is text data type.

Sales invoice lines is an order line table with decimal number data type on the [Line Amount] column, and the [LocationID] column is text data type.

The results I have gotten thus far:

So, when I put my measure in a callout card the values returned do change by [LocationID] selected in a slicer, however all of the values are incorrect.  When I put that same measure in a table visual that has the [LocationID] and [Line Amount] columns from the 'Sales invoice lines' the values that are returned are correctly calculated.  I tested for accuracy by dividing the sum of [Line Amount] by [LocationID] over the sum of total [Line Amount] for the Sales Invoice Lines Table and found the measure did in fact calculate this correctly.

I do not want to present this data with a table visual, but it does not work in any other presentation.  What do you think could be the issue?  How can I test for root cause?

Other considerations:

- The LocationIDList table is not connected in the relational model at all, so that is not the cause.
- Using an if statement for each site has not worked either.  Previously I told Power BI DAX to sum line amount filtered to a specific location id if a given location id from the LocationIDList table's LocationID column was selected.
- **There are no column filters being added that would change the results in the two different use cases mentioned above**.  I have accounted for this case.

Comment: For debugging, e.g., you could change you measure to RETURN the numerator and denominator respectively. Then compare these values in the different visuals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@anonymous gave some good advice that worked for me.  For anyone experiencing this issue on a report, break out the measure's different sections into other measures, and most importantly make a new page without any filters on it.  The filters that were applied to that page didn't seem like they would affect the numbers, but they were.

Comment: Glad you solved it! If it is enough to see/check the sections one by one, one can just use the one measure and replace the reference after RETURN accordingly. To keep the original part of code also in the measure while debugging, one can  “de-activate” lines by commenting them out with  ‘//‘